# How to use a Foreach loop in PHP/Blade for Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

Here is a quick question:
Is there any way to optimise this code with a foreach loop or something like this?

```
@if(isset($tags[0]))
    <span class="label label-primary">{{ $tags[0] }}</span>
@endif
@if(isset($tags[1]))
    <span class="label label-primary">{{ $tags[1] }}</span>
@endif
@if(isset($tags[2]))
    <span class="label label-primary">{{ $tags[2] }}</span>
@endif
@if(isset($tags[3]))
    <span class="label label-primary">{{ $tags[3] }}</span>
@endif
@if(isset($tags[4]))
    <span class="label label-primary">{{ $tags[4] }}</span>
@endif
@if(isset($tags[5]))
    <span class="label label-primary">{{ $tags[5] }}</span>
@endif
@if(isset($tags[6]))
    <span class="label label-primary">{{ $tags[6] }}</span>
@endif
@if(isset($tags[7]))
    <span class="label label-primary">{{ $tags[7] }}</span>
@endif
@if(isset($tags[8]))
    <span class="label label-primary">{{ $tags[8] }}</span>
@endif
@if(isset($tags[9]))
    <span class="label label-primary">{{ $tags[9] }}</span>
@endif
```

Thank you and have a nice day/night !

Answer (score 14):

You can do it simply like this :

```
@foreach ($tags as $tag)
    <span class="label label-primary">{{ $tag }}</span>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Shouldn't `{{ $tags }}` be `{{ $tag }}`? (Without the `s`)

Answer (score 5):

You can use an `@foreach` loop (as suggested by other answers) or an `@for` loop. Use `blade` syntax for control structures (preceeded by an `@` symbol)

```
@for($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++)
@if(isset($tags[$i]))
<span class="label label-primary">{{ $tags[$i] }}</span>
@endif
@endfor
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I finally understood how for loop works !

Comment: No problem. And just so you're aware, a "thank you" comment is always nice, but should be avoided in favour of an action that actually closes the question. All of the answers posted here are valid; so consider upvoting them and marking one as an answer.

Comment: Haha, no, you upvoted my comment :P And I said upvote "them", not just mine.

Comment: Why, given an indexed array, would you need to range over 9 indices? @foreach will range over each of the elements in the $tags array.

Comment: @jcorry You're not wrong; `@foreach` would be more efficient, and yeah I worded it wrong, but using a `@for` loop is still valid. The other answers have already provided a different approach to this, so your comment has already been addressed.

Comment: _A `for` loop would make more sense than a `foreach`_ How, exactly?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton "and yeah I worded it wrong" What do you want from me haha. I'll edit that out, jeeze.

Comment: @TimLewis That wording is much better, thank you. :)

Answer (score 4):

Per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade), you can do `@for` loops.

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    @if(isset($tags[$i]))
         <span class="label label-primary">{{ $tags[$i] }}</span>
    @endif
@endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($tags as $data) 
<span class="label label-primary">{{$data->property }}</span> 
@endforeach
```

you can also use the for else in blade just see the laravel docs 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade